# Inputmask jquery начало маски с 8ки?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Все привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, поставил этот скрипт "[Inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask)" 
Ставлю такую маску { "mask": "8(###)###-##-##", "type": "mobile" } она выглядит так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
мне необходимо чтобы по умолчанию стояла "8ка". Где это можно подправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот подключенный код [клик](https://codeshare.io/5e0lbL)

Comment: Прощу прощения вот https://codeshare.io/5e0lbL

Comment: добавьте ваш код в вопрос

Comment: Нужно добавить в вопрос сам код, а не ссылку на него.

Comment: @AK есть сомнение, что автор сможет добавить весь код плагина)

Comment: Как-то жестоко костылять код этой либы, чтобы поставить восьмёрку. Более правильный вариант такой. Первая ссылка в вопросе ведёт на гитхаб, там приведены примеры, как задать маску, там только три символа приведены, остальное нужно делать при помощи расширений.

Comment: как вариант сменить плагин на **[maskedinput](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput)**, тогда ваша задача решится так `$("#phone").mask("8(999)999-99-99")`

Comment: @Alex Спасибо. Я js коде вообще ничего не понимаю- пришлось отправлять код полностью) В maskedinput проблема, на раних версиях андройд - при заполнении переносит курсор на конец инпута тогда телефон пишется с конца.

Comment: @A K Спасибо. Буду ковырять "Inputmask" дальше, жаль нет быстрого решения проблемы.